# How can I make UnIconize produce formatted Strings? (or, how can I get UnIconize Wrap RawBoxes around Boxes?)

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, boxes, iconize

UnIconize from the menu turns RawBoxes into Box forms:

If I Iconize the right-hand side of this:

[image: Simple Plot with formatted text strings]

And then Uniconize it,

the formatted strings are appear as Box forms:

```
aPlot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"r/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(min\)]\)", 
    "E/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(min\)]\)"}]
```

I can "fix" this by copying and pasting the String and use RawBoxes

```
RawBoxes /@ {"r/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(min\)]\)", 
  "E/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(E\), \(min\)]\)"}
```

And then copy that result back into the UnIconized expression.

However, if I want to distribute my notebook to beginners who might UnIconize my code, the Boxes in the text will confuse them.

Is there any way of getting UnIconize to wrap RawBoxes around formatted strings?  It would have to be automatic and be invisible to beginner users.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. How did you do the iconizing (did you just wrap with Iconize?), and which subexpression exactly did you iconize?

Comment: I used the menu (or a shortcut) to iconize the righthand side of the screen shot (Copying and pasting that by itself already converts it to the \!\(... form.  After iconizing, uniconize it with the menu or short cut, you should see that the RawBoxes format has be converted to a \!\(... form.